# Record Access to External users

Tags: force.com-sites

We have a force.com site using which we are receiving product inquiries into Salesforce and storing in a Custom Object.

As soon as a new product inquiry is received, I need to send an email with a link to this record to an external vendor (who will fulfill the inquiry). The external vendor doesn't have access to Salesforce.

Using this link, they should be able to open the record.

How can I accomplish this? Do I need to create a Community for this?

Comment: Just add another page to your site.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit ? how adding a page will help?

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson I added another page to my site to display the record.